# Verificar quais itens no json tem determinado valor

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, como verificar quais os itens têm valor igual a 0 (estoque 0), o json e carregado por ajax.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response), function (i, deliveryTypes) {
      for (var i in deliveryTypes) {
            if(deliveryTypes[i].stockLevel != 0) {
                alert('diferente 0');
            } else {
                alert('igual 0');
            }
            }
    });
```

objetivo: se o valor do item (chave) "stockLevel" for igual a 0 exibo uma mensagem alertando o
usuario.

json:

```
{
  "deliveryTypes": [
    {
      "name": "5326",
      "estimatedDays": "7",
      "price": "R$ 1,09",
      "stockLevel": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "3048",
      "estimatedDays": "2",
      "price": "R$ 11,00",
      "stockLevel": "0"
    },
    {
      "name": "MO00001000",
      "estimatedDays": "2",
      "price": "R$ 11,00",
      "stockLevel": "23"
    },
    {
      "name": "3045",
      "estimatedDays": "0",
      "price": "",
      "stockLevel": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Adicione mais uma condicional no if, verificando se é vazio: `if(deliveryTypes[i].stockLevel != 0 || deliveryTypes[i].stockLevel == "") {`

Comment: O problema é que você está iterando `deliveryTypes` enquanto deveria iterar sobre `deliveryTypes.deliveryTypes`. Sua variável `deliveryTypes` é um objeto que possui uma lista, não uma lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, basta você utilizar método `filter()`

```js
let json = {
   "deliveryTypes":[
      {
         "name":"5326",
         "estimatedDays":"7",
         "price":"R$ 1,09",
         "stockLevel":""
      },
      {
         "name":"3048",
         "estimatedDays":"2",
         "price":"R$ 11,00",
         "stockLevel":"0"
      },
      {
         "name":"MO00001000",
         "estimatedDays":"2",
         "price":"R$ 11,00",
         "stockLevel":"23"
      },
      {
         "name":"3045",
         "estimatedDays":"0",
         "price":"",
         "stockLevel":""
      }
   ]
}

var array = json.deliveryTypes

var arrayFilter = array.filter(value => {
  return value.stockLevel === "0"
})

if(arrayFilter.length > 0) {
  alert('Existe stockLevel com valor 0');
}
```

Comment: Com *arrow function*: `array.filter(it => it.stockLevel === "0")` :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss já estava editando! Com certeza fica mais legível.

Comment: @Marconi um detalhe que não especifiquei, precisaria verificar em qual campo "name" tem estoque igual a 0, pois ao verificar preciso adicionar a mensagem somento no produto com "name" especifico.

Comment: @josecarlos veja que no `arrayFilter` irá te retornar outro array com os mesmo campos, mas filtrado, agora basta iterar sobre ele.

Comment: Valeu a ajuda @Marconi

Comment: @josecarlos tmj!